# operator + in sparse matrix : I don't find any bug

Tags: c++, matrix, sparse-matrix, matrix-storage

Hi everybody I implementing a sparse matrix stored in Modified Compressed sparse row ! the constructor works fine, I can verify it but the operator+ have a strange behaviour : If I had a non zero value the sum doesn't compute the right result. 
the modified compressed sparse row method is described [here](http://www.iue.tuwien.ac.at/phd/wagner/node83.html) 
my minim working code is the follow :

```
# include <initializer_list>
# include <vector>
# include <iosfwd>
# include <string>
# include <cstdlib>
# include <cassert>
# include <iomanip>
# include <cmath>
# include <set>
# include <fstream>
# include <algorithm>
# include <exception>

template <typename data_type>
class MCSRmatrix;             

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os ,const MCSRmatrix<T>& m) noexcept ;


template <typename T>
MCSRmatrix<T> operator+(const MCSRmatrix<T>& m1, const MCSRmatrix<T>& m2 ) ;

template <typename data_type>
class MCSRmatrix {

   public:
      using itype = std::size_t ;

      template <typename T>
      friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os ,const MCSRmatrix<T>& m) noexcept ;

      template <typename T>
      friend MCSRmatrix<T> operator+(const MCSRmatrix<T>& m1, const MCSRmatrix<T>& m2 ) ;

   public: 

      constexpr MCSRmatrix( std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<data_type>> rows);

      constexpr MCSRmatrix(const std::size_t& ) noexcept; 

      const data_type& operator()(const itype r , const itype c) const noexcept ;

      data_type operator()(const itype r , const itype c) noexcept ;

      auto constexpr printMCSR() const noexcept ;

   private:

     std::vector<data_type> aa_ ;    // vector of value 
     std::vector<itype>     ja_ ;    // pointer vector 

     int dim ; 

     std::size_t constexpr findIndex(const itype row ,  const itype col) const noexcept ;
};

template <typename T>
constexpr MCSRmatrix<T>::MCSRmatrix( std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> rows)
{
      this->dim  = rows.size();
      auto _rows = *(rows.begin());

      aa_.resize(dim+1);
      ja_.resize(dim+1);

      if(dim != _rows.size())
      {
          throw std::runtime_error("Error in costructor! MCSR format require square matrix!");  
      }

      itype w = 0 ;
      ja_.at(w) = dim+2 ;
      for(auto ii = rows.begin(), i=1; ii != rows.end() ; ++ii, i++)
      {
          for(auto ij = ii->begin(), j=1, elemCount = 0 ; ij != ii->end() ; ++ij, j++ )   
          {
              if(i==j)
                 aa_[i-1] = *ij ;
              else if( i != j && *ij != 0 )
              {   
                 ja_.push_back(j); 
                 aa_.push_back(*ij); 
                 elemCount++ ;
              }
              ja_[i] = ja_[i-1] + elemCount;           
          }
      }     
      printMCSR();
}





template <typename T>
constexpr MCSRmatrix<T>::MCSRmatrix(const std::size_t& n ) noexcept
{
         this->dim = n;
         aa_.resize(dim+1); 
         ja_.resize(dim+1);

      for(std::size_t i = 0; i < aa_.size()-1 ; i++)
        aa_.at(i) = 1 ;    

      for(std::size_t i = 0; i < ja_.size() ; i++)
        ja_.at(i) = aa_.size()+1 ;   


}     


template <typename T>
std::size_t constexpr MCSRmatrix<T>::findIndex(const itype row ,  const itype col) const noexcept 
{    
     assert( row > 0 && row <= dim && col > 0 && col <= dim ); 
     if(row == col)
     {
       return row-1;
     }
     int i = -1;

      for(int i = ja_.at(row-1)-1 ; i < ja_.at(row)-1 ; i++ )
      {
            if( ja_.at(i) == col ) 
            { 
              return i ;
            }
      }
      return -1;
}


template <typename T>
inline auto constexpr MCSRmatrix<T>::printMCSR() const noexcept 
{
      for(auto& x : aa_ )
          std::cout << x << ' ' ;
      std::cout << std::endl;

      for(auto& x : ja_ )
          std::cout << x << ' ' ;
      std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
const T& MCSRmatrix<T>::operator()(const itype r , const itype c) const noexcept 
{     
     auto i = findIndex(r,c); 
     if( i != -1 && i < aa_.size() )
     {      
            return aa_.at(i) ;
     }
     else
     {
            return aa_.at(dim) ;
     }       
}


template <typename T>
T MCSRmatrix<T>::operator()(const itype r , const itype c) noexcept 
{     
     auto i = findIndex(r,c); 
     if( i != -1 && i < aa_.size() )
     {      
            return aa_.at(i) ;
     }
     else
     {
            return aa_.at(dim) ;
     }       
}

// non member operator

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os ,const MCSRmatrix<T>& m) noexcept 
{
     for(std::size_t i=1 ; i <= m.dim ; i++ )
     {       
         for(std::size_t j=1 ; j <= m.dim ; j++)   
            os << std::setw(8) << m(i,j) << ' ' ;
         os << std::endl;   
     } 
     return os;
}


// perform sum by 2 Mod Comp Sparse Row matrices 
template <typename T>
MCSRmatrix<T> operator+(const MCSRmatrix<T>& m1, const MCSRmatrix<T>& m2 )
{
      if(m1.dim != m2.dim)
      {
          throw std::runtime_error("Matrixs dimension does not match! Error in operator +");  
      }
      else
      {
         MCSRmatrix<T> res(m1.dim);



         for(auto i=0; i < res.dim ; i++)
            res.aa_.at(i) = m1.aa_.at(i)  + m2.aa_.at(i) ; 

         res.ja_.at(0) = res.dim+2;

         std::set<unsigned int> ctrl; 


         int n1=0, n2=0, j1=0 , j2 =0;
         for(auto i=0 ; i < res.dim  ; i++)
         {

           ctrl.clear();

           n1 = m1.ja_.at(i+1)- m1.ja_.at(i) ;
           n2 = m2.ja_.at(i+1)- m2.ja_.at(i) ;


           j1=0 , j2=0 ;

           auto sum1 = 0. , sum2 = 0. , sum=0.;


            for(auto j = 0; j < std::max(n1,n2) ; j++ )
            {
               if(n1 && n2) 
               {
                 if(m1.ja_.at(m1.ja_.at(i)-1 + j1 ) == m2.ja_.at(m2.ja_.at(i)-1 + j2)) 
                 {
                     ctrl.insert(m1.ja_.at(m1.ja_.at(i)-1 + j1 ));

                     sum = m1.aa_.at(m1.ja_.at(i)-1 + j1 ) + m2.aa_.at(m2.ja_.at(i)-1 + j2) ;


                 }
                 else if(m1.ja_.at(m1.dim+1 + j1 ) != m2.ja_.at(m2.dim+1 + j2))
                 {   
                     ctrl.insert(m1.ja_.at(m1.ja_.at(i)-1 + j1 ));
                     ctrl.insert(m2.ja_.at(m1.ja_.at(i)-1 + j2 ));

                     sum1 = m1.aa_.at(m1.ja_.at(i)-1 + j1);               
                     sum2 = m2.aa_.at(m2.ja_.at(i)-1 + j1);     
                 }
               }        
               else if(n1)
               {  
                  ctrl.insert(m1.ja_.at(m1.ja_.at(i)-1 + j1 ));
                  sum1 = m1.aa_.at(m1.ja_.at(i)-1 + j1);               
               }
               else if(n2)
               {
                  ctrl.insert(m2.ja_.at(m2.ja_.at(i)-1 + j2 ));
                  sum2 = m2.aa_.at(m2.ja_.at(i)-1 + j2);     
               }
               if(sum1)
               {
                  res.aa_.push_back(sum1);
                  res.ja_.push_back(m1.ja_.at(m1.ja_.at(i)-1 + j1)) ;
               }
               if(sum2)
               {
                  res.aa_.push_back(sum2);
                  res.ja_.push_back(m2.ja_.at(m2.ja_.at(i)-1 + j2 ));
               }
               if(sum)
               {    

                    res.aa_.push_back(sum);
                    res.ja_.push_back(m1.ja_.at(m1.ja_.at(i)-1 + j1 ));
               }

               if(j1 < n1) j1++ ;
               if(j2 < n2) j2++ ;
             } 


            res.ja_.at(i+1) = res.ja_.at(i) + ctrl.size() ;  

         }
         return res ;   
      }
}
```

this is the main program :

```
# include "ModifiedCSRmatrix.H"

using namespace std ;


int main() {

   MCSRmatrix<int> m01 =  {{0,1,0,0},{0,3,0,0},{0,0,0,3},{0,0,0,1}};
   MCSRmatrix<int> m02 =  {{1,1,0,14},{0,22,0,3},{0,0,33,34},{0,0,1,44}};

     cout << endl; 
    MCSRmatrix<int> m03 = m01+m02 ;   

   cout << m03 << endl;
   cout << endl;
   m03.printMCSR();   




  return 0;
}
```

this particular 2 matrix give me the right result ! that is :

```
1        2        0       17 
0       25        0        3 
0        0       33       37 
0        0        1       45
```

but if i change the value of element `(3,2)` in the `m01` matrix ..
and so the matrix became :

```
 MCSRmatrix<int> m01 =  {{0,1,0,0},{0,3,0,0},{0,2,0,3},{0,0,0,1}};
```

the code give me this wrong result :

```
  1        2        0        0 
  0       25        0       14 
  0        2       33        0 
  0        0        0       45
```

but looking to the vector `aa_` (the vector of value in which the first `matrix.dim` are the element of diagonal and the element that follow are the off-diag non zero element looks that the matrix is different from this result )
they are :

```
aa_ = 1 25 33 45 0 2 2 14 2 3 3 1 1 
ja_ = 6 8 9 10 11 2 2 4 2 4 4 3 3
```

one other example if I had this line into the main :

```
 MCSRmatrix<double> m3  = {{1.01, 0 , 0,0}, {0, 4.07, 0,0},{0,0,6.08,0},{1.06,0,2.2,9.9} };   

  MCSRmatrix<double> m4  = {{ 1.21, 0 , 1.06,0 }, {0, 3.31, 1.06,0},{0,1.06,-6.01,0},{4.12,0,1.06,-8.3}}; 

  MCSRmatrix<double> m5 = m3+m4 ;  

  cout << m5 ;
```

give me the correct result :

```
    2.22        0     1.06        0 
       0     7.38     1.06        0 
       0     1.06     0.07        0 
    5.18        0     3.26      1.6
```

if I change for example m1 and m2 just a bit :

```
 MCSRmatrix<double> m6  = {{1.01, 0 , 0,0}, {0, 4.07, 0,0},{0,0,6.08,0},{1.06,0,2.2,9.9} }; 
MCSRmatrix<double> m7  = {{ 1.21, 0 , 0,2.15 }, {0, 3.31, 1.03,0},{0,1.06,-6.01,1.01},{4.12,1.1,1.06,-8.3}};
cout << m6+m7 ;
```

this program exit with `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'`

Answer (score 0):

In the part of the add loop where you're setting `sum1` and `sum2`, you don't want to do both, only the one with the lower index value.  This is because the higher column number could be in the other matrix but further in the row.

Also, the index calculation for `sum2` should be using `j2` and not `j1`.

Comment: thanks for reply .. could you explain better ? how can I chose the lower index value and so choese which sum1 or sum2 have to use ?

Comment: I've change the index in the computation of sum2 (but nothing change). Inside the `else if(m1.ja_.at(m1.dim+1 + j1 ) != m2.ja_.at(m2.dim+1 + j2))` I have to perform 2 sum, the fact that `m1.ja_.at(m1.dim+1 + j1 ) != m2.ja_.at(m2.dim+1 + j2)` means if exist a non zero in `m1.aa_[index1]` that is different from `m2.aa_[index2]`, so this 2 component give two contribute to the vector `res.aa_`